# How to write multiple DataStream's to a single file

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say I have two `DataStream`'s of different types:

```
val stream1: DataStream[(Int, Int, Int)] = ...
val stream2: DataStream[(Int, Int, Int, Int, Float)] = ...
```

How can I write **both streams** into a **single file**?

I've tried different things, but don't seem to work. For instance, I can't just write straight away as

```
stream1.writeAsText("path/to/file.txt").setParallelism(1)
stream2.writeAsText("path/to/file.txt").setParallelism(1)
```

because Flink will complain with the following message:

```
java.io.IOException: File or directory already exists.
Existing files and directories are not overwritten in NO_OVERWRITE mode. 
Use OVERWRITE mode to overwrite existing files and directories.
```

On the other hand, I can't overwrite like this:

```
stream1.writeAsText("path/to/file.txt").setParallelism(1)
stream2.writeAsText("path/to/file.txt", FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE).setParallelism(1)
```

because (as far as I understand) the second stream will overwrite whatever the first stream wrote.

Finally, I thought about connecting the stream like this

```
val connectedStream: ConnectedStream = stream1.connect(stream2)
```

but then I'd get a `ConnectedStream`, which doesn't have a `writeAsText` method.

(For the record, I actually have 4 streams that I'd like to write to a single file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution is to use for each stream a mapper to map each event into a `String` (or another common type such as `byte[]`). Then you have four streams with the same type (`DataStream[String]`) which you can union into a single stream and write as one stream into a file.

This would look as follows:

```
val s1: DataStream[String] = ???
val s2: DataStream[String] = ???
val s3: DataStream[String] = ???
val s4: DataStream[String] = ???

val out: DataStream[String] = s1.union(s2).union(s3).union(s4)
out.writeAsText("path/to/file")
```

Comment: Thank you! But how could I extend this solution to 4 streams? If I join 2 streams I get a `JoinedStream`, that doesn't have a `join` method to join "in chain" with the remaining 2 streams...

Comment: I said `union` not `join`. These are different operations. I added example code to my answer.